# How do I use the -e option in PHP?

Tags: php, debugging, command-line, profiling, command-line-arguments

`php` on the command line tells me that it has an option:

```
  -e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
```

However by running my command line script with that I see nothing... what's that option for?

Answer (score 2):

This extended information are for debuggers and profilers. (eg. xdebug, or ZendDebugger)

Normaly this switch is used by IDE's with support for debugger (like Eclipse PDT)

see http://www.xdebug.org/docs/ for examples.

Comment: if you have an debugger configured for your cli or cgi-php you can force an error to see a stack trace. 
From the Xdebug website: "When Xdebug is activated it will show a stack trace whenever PHP decides to show a notice, warning, error etc. The information that stack traces display, and the way how they are presented, can be configured to suit your needs." (http://www.xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace)
the -e switch just enables a debuger/profiler to print more information.